# jQuery white label theme widget auto reload

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, widget

Recently I have purchased white label theme from theme forest. I am using widget plugin in my dashboard with auto reload functionality.

I want to use widget ajax reload plugin with my jQuery ajax call or with C# methods. is it possible? i tried with different options. But, no luck. Please help me.

BindWBE() is my C# method. is it possible to use like this may I use jQuery webmethod to call this?

```
 <div class="widget" id="Web Booking Engine" data-load="BindWBE()" data-reload="10" data-remove-content="false">
                <h3 class="handle">Web Booking Engine</h3>
                <div>
                    Ajax Content replaced here
                </div>
            </div>
```

**C# method:**

```
 public string BindWBE()
    {
        return "Ajax call";
    }
```

Any suggestions?